# Getting Enable application screen while integrating Dundas report, how can I load the Dundas Dashboard?

Tags: javascript, dundas

I am trying to integrate Dundas Dashboard in angular application, when try to get it loaded, getting enable application page while loading it on html.

Below image contains how page look like.

[image: click here for image]

Error:

[image: error image]

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because you have embedded Dundas BI cross-domain over HTTP.

Due to the changes in [Chrome and others regarding SameSite cookies](https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site), when a web application is embedded through an iFrame cross-domain the cookies must be marked with SameSite and must be Secure, as such it must be embedded via HTTPS (not HTTP).

You can install and run Dundas BI locally on your machine, [including through docker](https://www.dundas.com/support/learning/documentation/installation/using-dundas-bi-docker-containers), if you want to test embedding it via HTTP locally.

As a note, the `DOMException` in the last image is for information only and isn't an error. The only error is the `440` for the session which is occurring because the session can't be sent due to the aforementioned HTTP cross-domain embedding.

Comment: yes, as it's cross domain, I've applied self signed certificate and it's resolved my problem, thanks @automation

Comment: @vidhyadharmote great! Please mark as the answer if this solved it.